# Grammatical name and function of "the end of the day"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, noun-phrases, adjuncts

What's the grammatical name of *the end of the day* here, and what is its grammatical function?

The sentence is this:

> There was always a huge quantity of food left over at the end of the day.

Answer (score 2):

> There was always a huge quantity of food left over at [the end of the day].

The phrase *the end of the day* is a noun phrase. The Head noun in the noun phrase is the word *end*. It is functioning as the Complement of the preposition *at*. Some people would describe this as *the end of the day* being the *object* of the preposition *at*.

Just in case the question was actually intended to be "What is the name and function of *at the end of the day*?", that phrase is a preposition phrase. In terms of grammatical functions or grammatical relations it is a temporal Adjunct (read 'Adverbial').

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day is an **adverbial phrase**.  The clue is the preposition ‘at’.  Like any modifier, it modifies (tells us about) the event or action described by the verb.  In this case, it tells us **when** it took place.  So it is *temporal*.

Comment: But the 'adverbial' is ***at** the end of the day*. The OP is supposedly asking about the phrase *end of the day*, not *at the end of the day*.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, you are right.