# Is this prepositional phrase a supplement or modifier?

Tags: modifiers, adjuncts

> **In the morning**, he drove to work.

> **Now** he knew what to do.

Having read about supplements and modifiers (two types of adjunct), I have started to become confused. Supplements are considered to be non-essential, and the easiest way to identify them is to acknowledge their association with commas. However, none of the examples provided have addressed fronted adverbs and prepositional phrases, such as the ones above. They are always obvious supplements: sentence adverbials, non-restrictive participle clauses, non-restrictive appositives, absolute constructions, etc.

'Now' and 'In the morning' can be placed in different positions, and because of their shortness (the two examples being no more than three words), the commas are optional. I would say that they modify 'drove' and 'knew', respectively. This being the case, are they modifiers with and without commas?

Comment: The comma is not a foolproof test for supplementation. "In the morning" and "now" are temporal adjuncts in clause structure.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Please could you write this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grammatical name and function of '{at} the end of the day'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469819/grammatical-name-and-function-of-the-end-of-the-day/469823#469823) or  [Why is "for six years" not the adverbial complement in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553280/why-is-for-six-years-not-the-adverbial-complement-in-this-sentence)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They are useful, thanks. However, my question is primarily focused on identifying supplements. These examples were intended to clarify whether commas are an inarguable indicator of an adjunct being supplementary. As BillJ clarified, they are not.

Comment: Commas, being part of printed material, are not indicators of anything in English grammar.